# How to send a message to stage if AS3 FLVPlayback stream isn't found

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

I've successfully created an FLVPlayback component using the component library and it's playing the streaming video that I want it to. My question is, if that stream is not online or cannot be found, how would I go about displaying a message on the stage to let the user know, there is no active stream.

UPDATED:
Here's my code -

```
thestream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNCStatus);
function onNCStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    trace(event.info.code)
    switch (event.info.code) {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
            trace("Success");
            break;
        case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
            trace("Stream not found");
            break;
    }   
}
```

There's no output still. It seems like the function isn't getting invoked. However, if I place a trace outside the function (before it), I get a response:

`trace(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS);`

the output:

`netStatus`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put a listener on your component instance:

```
flvPlaybackComponent.addEventListener("netStatus", onNCStatus);

function onNCStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
 trace(event.info.code)
 switch (event.info.code) {
  case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
      trace("Success");
      break;
  case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
     trace("Stream not found");
     break;
 }   
}
```

Then just have your visual somewhere on stage and do what you need with it within the stream not found area of the listener function.

Comment: I'm having troubles getting the function to work. I've replaced `flvPlaybackComponent` with the FLVPlayback instance name `thestream` but I'm not getting anything in the Output tab when I try to export.

Comment: I edited my code above to trace out every status code. This will at least trace something if the instance name is correct. Give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: mind posting your fla for it? this part: trace(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS); is just tracing the name of the event you're looking for, not the actual instance. It's kinda like doing trace("hi") - it only returns what you're asking for, not the actual event that is firing.

Comment: I would really just suggest to do your video player in code, since the component is a bit crazier to deal with, but if all you need that's not working is to be able to throw an error when you have an invalid source, it by reworking your code like so: http://pastebin.com/aU7WXd2Q - basically, take out the source URL in the properties panel of your component, put that in the actions panel as a property of your player instance, then do a try/catch if it can't find the file (all this is in that pastbin link btw)

Comment: Ran out of time to try this more at work, but I'll be able to put some time in during the weekend. Thanks for the head start and I'll update this thread as soon as I make some progress.

Answer (score 0):

Use the STATE_CHANGE Event of the FLVPlayback Component, and check for the state if it is an CONNECTION_ERROR.
You also can check in there if your video has started playing, if it has finished playing and so on.

The below code is a sample that you can use as documentclass for an as3 fla:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
    import fl.video.VideoEvent;
    import fl.video.VideoState;
    public class Player extends Sprite
    {
        public var playback:FLVPlayback;

        public function Player()
        {
            playback.addEventListener(VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE, onStateChange);
        }

        private function onStateChange(ev:VideoEvent):void
        {
            if (ev.state == VideoState.CONNECTION_ERROR)
            {
                trace("could not load video");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: To get your above updated code working, change the NetStatus Event to the STATE_CHANGE Event:

```
thestream.addEventListener(VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE, onNCStatus);
   function onNCStatus(event:VideoEvent):void {
       trace(event.info.code)
       switch (event.state) {
           case VideoState.CONNECTION_ERROR:
               trace("Stream not found/Could not connect to stream");
               break;
       }   
   }
```

The FLVPlayBack component does NOT dispatch the NetStatus Event.

Comment: Malyngo, I tried your code, but I get an error on line 2 `Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 2 1037: Packages cannot be nested.
`

Comment: You are putting the above code into a frame script, that is why it is not working. Just use the line **playback.addEventListener(VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE, onStateChange);** and the code for the function **onStateChange** if you want to use it as a framescript. You may have to omit the private on the function, so it only is like **function onStateChange(ev:VideoEvent):void{ ... }**

Comment: Intersting. I'll give it a run.

Comment: Well, I got it working so that it traces out 'Playing' and 'Buffering' messages every few seconds, but when I disconnect the server from streaming, I don't get a message in the output that states there isn't any stream connected. This is driving me nuts! ;o

Answer (score 0):

flvPlaybackComponent.addEventListener(*NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS*, onNCStatus);

Difficult to tell without seeing your code.  As a start, it's good practice to ensure there are never strings in your code for functionality, so you should replace the string "netStatus" with NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS which is a static constant variable.